# aex:repeat can't display null values in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat, null

Hi I've forcefully added a null value inside a list so when I create a table I can see empty cells. Is the behavior of apex:repeat not displaying null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation doesn't call this out, but apparently this is indeed a limitation. Make sure you do not output a *null* object in the iterator. You can have an *empty* object, though, so a wrapper class with blank values, or an empty string, etc, are all acceptable.